# Dynamically implementing horizontal scrolling of gridview in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

My discussion can be seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/dea7qfth/1/).

I have `myBox` `div`. Inside has `col-sm-9 div` and `col-sm-9 div` has different sections.

Now I show only section1.
Inside section1 has gridview with 2 x 4 grid elements.
This is just a concept.

In actual implementation, this number of elements in gridview is dynamic.
Say database has 1000 data, gridview has to allocate 2 x 500 grid elements inside gridview. Then I need horizontal scrolling.
My queries are

(1)How to implement horizontal scrolling if I have grid elements for more than one page? I'd like to fix one page is allocated 8 grid elements (2 x 4) only.

(2)How can I implement it dynamically in Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: try horizontal lazy loading

Comment: @AmiteshKumar any good esamples for it?

Comment: @AmiteshKumar thanks. That is what I want.

Comment: This is a perfect tutorial (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)